# Instance of 'Future' return instead of return some value

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a function, which is called on one page, I need to return some value **e.g** status code or a string to the previous page for some calculation where I am calling this function. but I get   `Instance of 'Future'`  instead of value. I feel trouble figuring out what I am missing here.

```
class Update {
  Future updateData(
      String name,
      ) async {
        somedata={
          "name": name
        }
    String jsonBody = json.encode(somedata);
    await http
        .put(
      Uri.parse('Some API call'),
      body: jsonBody,
      headers: {
        some header
      },
    ).then(
          (response) {
        if (response.statusCode == 200) {
          return "sucess";
        }
        else if(response.statusCode == 401){
           return "Sign in again";
        }
      },
    ).catchError(
          (e) {
        if (kDebugMode) {
          Center(
            child: Text(
                "$e"
            ),
          );
        }
      },
    );
  }
}
```

**Function calling on a page**

```
var getResponce= Update().updateData(event_title.text,)
            print(getResponce);
```

Here on this print I get instance of future instead of value.

**What I tried**

```
class Update {
  Future<String?> updateData();
```

Here on this print, I get an instance of Future<String?> instead of value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Order to get Future value you have to `await` for it, try this:

```
var getResponce= await Update().updateData(event_title.text,)
print(getResponce);
```

then change your `Update` to this:

```
class Update {
  Future updateData(String name) async {
    somedata={
      "name": name
    }
    String jsonBody = json.encode(somedata);
    var response = await http
        .put(Uri.parse('Some API call'), body: jsonBody
            headers: {
              some header
            },
            )
        .catchError(
      (e) {
        if (kDebugMode) {
          Center(
            child: Text("$e"),
          );
        }
      },
    );

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      return "sucess";
    } else if (response.statusCode == 401) {
      return "Sign in again";
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It worked but I get null  in print(getResponce). event my status code is 200

Comment: great, it worked. but why did you remove .then. or why exactly this restrict me to get the value ?

Comment: because when you put .then in Future function it wont return value inside then.